# The grass and the roofs vibrate/flicker

Tags: aframe

Using aframe online.
My 360 2D panos get vibrations areas (grass, roofs seen from the sky (drone panos))

I get the problem with Quest 2 and Quest 3 headsets.
Problem occurs with official Meta Browser, with Wolvic too.

To get rid of those areas vibrating, I use sidequest, and boost settings.

Watching same panos from the local storage of my headsets, there is no flickering/vibration.

Here is the code I use - Iframe 1.4 and iframe.min.js

```
<div id="myEmbeddedScene">
    <a-scene embedded>
        <a-assets>
            <!-- Définition du panoramique -->
            <img id="Panoramique" crossorigin src="/panoramiques/panoramas/folder/pano.JPG">
        </a-assets>
        <a-sky src="#Panoramique" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-sky>
        <a-entity class="link"></a-entity>
        <a-text value="Town" color="black" font="/vr/font/segoe-print-msdf.json" negate="false" position="-1 6.5 -6">
        </a-text>
        <!-- audio -->
        <a-entity id="my-sound" geometry="primitive: plane" material="color: white" position="0 10 0"
            sound="src: url(/vr/audio/one.mp3); autoplay: true; startEvents: click">
        </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</div>
```